# Retry a Jenkins pipeline job on a specific error message

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline

So without Jenkins Pipeline the Naginator Plugin allows to restart a specific build on failure using regular expressions.

I like the retry option in Jenkins pipeline but I am not sure if I can catch an error from the build in the catch block and do a retry.

Is there a way to do so?

Eg: I have jenkins build which runs make. now make fails with an error: "pg_config.h missing". I want to catch this error and retry the build again a couple of times.

How can I do the above? Also, is it possible to catch multiple errors similar to regular expressions in Naginator somehow using pipelines?

Answer (score 2):

```
  retry("3"){
    try {
      sh "${cmd} 2>&1 > cmdOutput.txt"
      sh "cat cmdOutput.txt"
    } catch(FlowInterruptedException interruptEx) {
      throw interruptEx
    } catch(err) {
      def cmdOutput = readFile('cmdOutput.txt').trim()
      if (cmdOutput.contains("pg_config.h missing")) {
        error "Command failed with error : ${err}. Retrying ...."
      } else {
        echo "Command failed with error other than `pg_config.h missing`"
      }
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I use the 'waitUntil' step and a counter to retry a shell command. I capture the output of the shell command so that I can run regex checks against the output and then continue or exit the loop.

```
// example pipeline
pipeline {
    agent {
        label ""
    }
    stages {
        // stage('clone repo') {
        //     steps {
        //         git url: 'https://github.com/your-account/project.git'
        //     }
        // }

        // stage ('install') {
        //     steps {
        //         sh 'npm install'
        //     }
        // }

        stage('build') {
            steps {
                script {
                    // wrap with timeout so the job aborts if no activity
                    timeout(activity: true, time: 5, unit: 'MINUTES') {
                        // loop until the inner function returns true
                        waitUntil {
                            // setup or increment "count" counter and max value
                            count = (binding.hasVariable('count')) ? count + 1 : 1
                            countMax = 3

                            println "try: $count"

                            // Note: you must include the "|| true" after your command, 
                            // so that the exit code always returns as 0. The "sh" command is
                            // actually running '/bin/sh -xe'. The '-e' option forces the script
                            // to exit on non-zero exit code. Prevent this by forcing a 0 exit code
                            // by adding "|| true"

                            // execute command and capture stdout
                            // Uncomment one of these 3 lines to test different conditions.
                            output = sh returnStdout: true, script: 'echo "Finished: SUCCESS" || true'
                            // output = sh returnStdout: true, script: 'echo "BUILD FAILED" || true'
                            // output = sh returnStdout: true, script: 'echo "something else happened" || true'

                            // show the output in the log
                            println output

                            // run different regex tests against the output to check the state of your build
                            buildOK = output ==~ /(?s).*Finished: SUCCESS.*/
                            buildERR = output ==~ /(?s).*BUILD FAILED.*/

                            // then check your conditions
                            if (buildOK) {
                                return true     // success, so exit loop
                            } else if (buildERR) {
                                if (count >= countMax) {
                                    // count exceeds threshold, so throw an error (exits pipeline)
                                    error "Retried $count times. Giving up..."
                                }
                                // wait a bit before retrying
                                sleep time: 5, unit: 'SECONDS'
                                return false    // repeat loop
                            } else {
                                // throw an error (exits pipeline)
                                error 'Unknown error - aborting build'
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
    // post {
    //     always {
    //         cleanWs notFailBuild: true
    //     }
    // }
}
```